# in telerk mvc grid, editing and inserting scenarioes with AJAX binding of complex objects

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, grid, telerik, edit

In Telerik documentation we must use server binding when binding complex objects.

How can we activating Insertion and Editing mode in Telerik mvc grid with ajax binding of complex objects?

how we can customize the whole of insert form and edit form

ie. drawing drop down lists for properties of reference types

thanks in advance

Comment: please correct your title, your question will remain for future readers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

I am using Client Edit Templates for this scenario but there is a problem in the ScriptRegisterar I think, the problem related to registering Telerik DropDown javascript files.

I made initial solution which is to add a line of code to the ScriptRegisterar to explicit register the javascript file "telerik.list.js"

OR add a dummy Telerik DropDown list in the same page where you want it to appear in the grid, and you have to hide it using css.

**This is a bug in the final version of telerik 2010.3.1110**

Telerik has released the hotfix for this bug in the version 2010.3.1111

check the link and download the hotfix:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/script-registrar-not-loading-scripts-for-controls-used-in-client-templates.aspx

Answer (score 0):

How about using server edit template for that, is it applicable? I crawled the online MVC demos on their site and hit upon [this one](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/serveredittemplates).

Comment: I know their demos, I am asking about AJAX BINDING not SERVER BINDING and exactly AJAX BINDING of COMPLEX OBJECTS so don't paste the link: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editingajax